# Convertions with integer

Tags: python

I want to enter an integer and I want python to return my statement with a convertion. I don't know how to fix this issue. Code below

````
subjectConversions = {
  "1": "Computer science",
  "2": "Geography",
  "3": "History",
  "4": "French",
  "5": "Drama",
  "6": "Music",
  "7": "Art",
  "8": "Design & Technology",
  "9": "Physical Education",
  "10": "Cooking",
  "11": "Business studies",
}

if year != "y":
  print("Sorry! Year 9 only!")
  quit()

elif year == "y":
  print("Welcome!")

print("Take a look at the list below for GCSE subjects. Once that is done, select four different options at each prompt.\nComputer Science [1], Geography [2], History [3], French [4], Drama [5], Music [6], Art [7], Desingn & Technology [8], Physical Education [9], Cooking [10], Business studies [11]\n")
Op1 = int(input("Option one: "))

print("You have selected" + (subjectConversions[Op1]) + ", is that correct? [y/n]")```
````

Comment: The keys of your dict should be integers like `1` instead of strings like `"1"` since you convert the user input `Op1` to `int`

Comment: Please don't add "[FIXED]" or similar phrases to your question title or body. Rather, you should [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that helped you the most. (Obviously, I'm not going to specify which one you should accept - it should just be whichever one you found the most helpful).

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```py
Op1 = int(input("Option one: "))
```

To:

```py
Op1 = input("Option one: ")
```

and it works, this is because you are asking for an integer while your keys are strings so you should ask for a string

Comment: The input is already a string by default - no need to do the conversion.

Comment: Changed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use integers as keys rather than str, that is replace

```
subjectConversions = {
  "1": "Computer science",
  "2": "Geography",
  "3": "History",
  "4": "French",
  "5": "Drama",
  "6": "Music",
  "7": "Art",
  "8": "Design & Technology",
  "9": "Physical Education",
  "10": "Cooking",
  "11": "Business studies",
}
```

using

```
subjectConversions = {
  1: "Computer science",
  2: "Geography",
  3: "History",
  4: "French",
  5: "Drama",
  6: "Music",
  7: "Art",
  8: "Design & Technology",
  9: "Physical Education",
  10: "Cooking",
  11: "Business studies",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use strings as keys and then try to access the values using integers - you need to pick one and be consistent. Either make the keys integers or keep the input as a string.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert to *integer* on `Op1 = int(input("Option one: "))`.
It should be good to only accepting *string*.
i.e:

```
Op1 = input("Option one: ")
```